# Handling Nested Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

I am learning regex with experimenting on HTML files, I have a regex problem,

My text is :

```
text='12<a>1<a>2</a>3</a>13<a>4<a>5</a>6</a>14'
```

The expression

```
<a><a></a></a> is nested
```

I want to write a regex that can handle nested expression, for example, my output for the above text should be

```
Output :    121314
```

I use the regex,

```
re.sub('<a>(.+?)</a>', '', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

I get an output:

```
'123</a>136</a>14'
```

This is because the regex is unable to handle nested expression.

Comment: `I am learning regex with experimenting on HTML files`, bad idea..

Comment: How about extracting only digits `re.sub('(\d+)', '', text, flags=re.DOTALL)`

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/194635

Comment: you should try lxml  or pyquery

Comment: That's so crazy each time there's regex and html in a post someone link to this. I agree parsing html with regex is a bad idea, but here the OP is asking to learn about regex, mainly a recursive regex in fact...

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with using regex to parse HTML. So long as the task is easy enough that regex could handle. I also can't see anything wrong with learning regex by experimenting on HTML. It stimulates so much creativities.

Comment: @Khoi Atually doing a recursive regex on brackets or anything opening/closing is doable, with HTML tags it gets harder by nature as the "separator" are of multiple chars.

Comment: @Tensibai are you saying that it's hard because it's HTML? Again, solving hard problem bring greater reward.

Comment: Python `re` regex module does not support recursive regex. You need to write your own parser here. With HTML strings, it means you should be using an HTML parser.

Comment: @Khoi just saying it's hard because HTML tags are not single char like brackets or parentheses, so avoiding them inside the tags is harder. That's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
while re.search(r'<a>\d*</a>', text):
    text = re.sub(r'<a>\d*</a>', '', text)
```

Comment: Thanks, Your answer handles the scenario perfectly. The problem is that I have simplified the tag to a greater extent and posted. Their can be digits, character even tags like <i></i> between <a> and </a>.

Comment: @Sam In this case follow the previous advices, don't use regex but a parser.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to fetch keywords from wikipedia page that are bold, itallic, hyperlinked, headings....,,,  at the same time I have to avoid the Images, Contents and tables from the wikkipedia page. I am not sure if it can be achieved by using a psrser

Comment: @Sam In that case you should have posted the full problem, albeit with carefully arranged scenario. Hope that did help you to some extent.

Answer (score -1):

```
re.sub(r"\b\d{0,1}\b<\/?a>\b\d{0,1}\b", r"", text)
```